# Workday service proxied through wso2 esb

Tags: proxy, wsdl, wso2, esb, workday-api

I was wondering if anyone else has found a relatively easy way of proxying a workday service to limit the operations to one or two operations.  Our Workday service we want to proxy has almost 200 operations in it and the WSDL is over 52,000 lines.  We would like to use ESB as a hub for our enterprise web services, but have not found an easy way to expose one or two operations, as we don't want to expose the world to everyone at this point.  Manually trying to trim a 52,000 line wsdl down to under 100 lines is a little daunting if it needs to be done for a couple dozen services and the wsdl is updated at least twice a year.

Has anyone had similar experiences or suggestions on tools that may be able to help create a custom wsdl to publish from our proxied service?  We don't have any java code to define the service and generate a wsdl.

Am I wrong thinking that I can limit the operations of my proxied service by creating a custom wsdl to expose only those operations we want for the given proxy?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Interesting question! I would first suggest you could limit people's access to workday web services by what security groups and domains you assign to their account, in Workday.  

Then, yes, you could wrap a limited number of services (from the original WSDL) and expose those through your own custom service in WSO2. However, this approach implies that WSO2 ESB is authenticating to Workday as a single, service account.  At this point though, you lose visibility (in workday) of who called the web service.

Answer (score 0):

You're right thinking that you can limit your service's operations like that. You have two way to create your "custom" wsdl :

Use tools like altova xmlsply for exemple and comment the operations you don't want to expose

Develop a script with ant for exemple and use xsl to automatically update your wsdl